# Spritekit - detect specific node using didbegincontact and touchesbegan

Tags: sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I have multiple enemy nodes on screen and i have a crosshair for aiming and touch anywhere to shoot & kill the enemy. i managed to detect when the crosshair is aiming at the enemy but i can't manage when i touch the screen to affect this specific enemy.

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {

            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else {

            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }


        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == CrosshairCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == EnemyCategory  {

            canShoot = true

        }

    }

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
  }
}
```

each enemy is an instance of a subclass with it's own health and behaviour. Now how can i get that specific enemy from the contact function so i can affect it in the touchesbegan funcition ?

```
 func createEnemy(sprite: String, position: CGPoint, name: String) {

        monster = Enemy(imageNamed: sprite)
        monster.position = position
        monster.name = name
        monster.size = CGSizeMake(56, 35)

        monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: monster.size.width / 2)
        monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = EnemyCategory
        monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CrosshairCategory
        monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        monster.moveEnemy()
        monster.createHealth()
        addChild(monster)

    }
  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

       createEnemy(enemyNode, position: CGPointMake(20,  200), name: "enemy1")
       createEnemy(blueStand, position: CGPointMake(20,  400), name: "enemy2")
}
```

I was considering creating several instances like (monster1 - monster2) instead of using the function call in didMoveToView  to create them, which then i can easily reference them in the touchesbegan function, but i don't know if that is the most efficient way of doing it.
I hope i have been clear enough about my problem :)

Update:

```
touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



 if canShoot {

                (secondBody.node as Enemy).healthPoints -= 20
                (secondBody.node as Enemy).removeAllChildren()
                (secondBody.node as Enemy).createHealth()
            }
```

Enemy.swift

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    var healthPoints: CGFloat = 60
    var redBar = SKSpriteNode()


func createHealth() {

        if healthPoints <= 0 {

            self.removeFromParent()
        } else {


            redBar = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(healthPoints, 5))
            redBar.position = CGPointMake(0, 30)
            self.addChild(redBar)
        }
    }

    func moveEnemy() {

//some code

    }
```

It now works fine, but i can only kill the first monster i create (aka healthPoints = 0) and then i get an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while attempt to kill more than one, meaning that only one monster behaves as it should be then i get the error, very strange.

Comment: Hi, I see you are assigning the bodies A and B to two local variables, firstBody and secondBody in the didBeginContact method. I think you could just make those two variable global, so you can access the enemy from the touchesBegan method.

Comment: bodies A and B & firstBody & secondBody are all type SKPhysics, i cannot convert that to SKSpriteNode which is the Enemy class is.

Comment: but Enemy inherits from SKSpriteNode right? couldn't you just do contact.bodyA.node and that would return the associated node which in this case is the Enemy?

Comment: because node is a read-only property of SKPhysicsBody which is the node that this body is connected to.

Comment: just declare firstBody & secondBody as SKNodes, or let them infer the type, and make them global.

Comment: Please, check the updated post. ^^

Comment: So, that solved your original question?

Comment: Yes & No, it still not working as it should, i still not sure if it's the best approach.